# Batch to append certain string to specific .txt file from predefined list?

Tags: batch-file

I am using a for loop to create textfiles with predefined headers, but I want to append a unique string (alice, bob, etc.) on the 2nd line for each file from a predetermined list.

```
Set a=alice
Set b=bob
Set c=chris

Rem ...etc. (I have about 30 files with a unique name to go in row 2 of each file)

For /l %%x in (1, 1 , 30) do (echo headerRow1 > file%%x.txt & echo %a% > file%%x.txt)
```

I dont understand how to automatically insert "bob" for the second iteration (ie. In "file2.txt") and  "chris" for the third iteration, and continue for 30 files.

Do I somehow loop the %a% part to increment by one each time. What should I name the string variables to do this? Are these even the right questions?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem you're trying to solve is to be able to iterate between *two* lists in one `for` loop, when the `for` loop can only iterate through *one* set at a time. The problem is harder in that arrays and lists don't really exist in Batch as first-class citizens.

There are multiple ways of solving this, but one simpler way is to loop through the names, and increment a counter each time through the loop. (This is probably easier than a `for /l` loop and incrementing the list of names.)

Here is an example.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set names=alice bob chris
set x=1
for %%a in (%names%) do (
    >file!x!.txt (
        echo headerRow
        echo %%a
    )
    set /a x+=1
)
```

Notes:

- Set all your names on a single line, and a `for` loop can iterate through them.
- Set your counter (x) at the start, then increment it at the end of the loop.
- I'm using delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) and the syntax of `!x!` instead of `%x%` so that Batch resolves the variable `x` each time through the loop, instead of once (and only once) the first time it goes through, so that it gets the right incremented value each time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That was an awesomely detailed answer. THANK YOU! You just made my Friday night :) I always wondered what delayedexpansion did.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40171884.txt"
SET "headerrow=This is your header"
SET "line2=This is line two for "
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" "%filename1%"') DO IF "%%b" neq "" (
>"%targetdir%\file%%a.txt" (
 ECHO(%headerrow%
 ECHO(%line2%%%b
 TYPE "%sourcedir%\thefilecontainingtheremainder.txt"
)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40171884.txt` containing your names for my testing.

Uses the file `"%sourcedir%\thefilecontainingtheremainder.txt"` to contain the body of the data to be assigned to the output file. Naturally, this could be anywhere.

Essentially, take the filename containing your names, and use `find /n /v ""` to prefix each line with `[sequencenumber]`. Using `delims` of `[]`, assign the prefix to `%%a` and the remainder of the line (the name) to `%%b`.

The first line output by `find` will report the filename, but won't contain `[]` (unless you get silly and engineer it that way), so `%%b` in that case will be empty. We skip that line, and for the others, `%%a` contains the number and `%%b` the name.

Then create new output files "file*number*.txt" and the two special lines - the second with `%%b` (the name) appended. Then regurgitate the remainder of the required text by simply `type`ing it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Magoo! That's a neat use of the find command. I'll probably use soja's method because it seems easier, but I will definitely use yours for further practice in batch file programming. Thanks for taking your time to help!